# Pressing on app notification always activates app window

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, notifications

My application schedules notification and displays it well

```
NSUserNotificationCenter.default.delegate = self

let notification = NSUserNotification()
notification.deliveryDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: TimeInterval(10))
notification.title = title
notification.actionButtonTitle = "Do something"

notification.soundName = notificationSound != "none" ? notificationSound : nil
notification.otherButtonTitle = "Close"

NSUserNotificationCenter.default.scheduleNotification(notification)
```

When I press on the button activation method is called well

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: NSUserNotificationCenter, didActivate notification: NSUserNotification) {
    DDLogDebug("Did activate notification")

    switch notification.activationType {
       ...
}
```

The problem is that opened window is activated after pressing on it that I don't need.

Application is agent (UIElement) with multiple windows opened. Tried non-agent application, the problem still persists - it activates main window

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately, I didn't find the answer. I implemented my own mechanism of notifications that displays custom Panel

Comment: Yes this is a problem, do you have a radar ticket for this?
Maybe we see progress with the new MenuBarExtra, as MenuBarExtra + Notifications + WindowGroup will always bring up the WindowGroup when clicking the Notification, which cannot be wanted.